# Workout the time difference between rows for a given group and using specified column as start of time

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have the following dataframe:

```
       id     key  serial    time
0  310000   first     100    2022-01-15 07:28:00
1  310000  second     100    2022-01-15 07:29:00 
3  450000   first     200    2022-01-15 07:45:00
4  450000  second     200    2022-01-15 07:46:00
5  450000   third     200    2022-01-15 07:47:00
```

I want to workout the time difference in seconds between rows given that:

- They have same id and same serial
- Start time for the group is if key=first exist. Otherwise null.

Ideal outcome:

```
       id     key  serial    time                  difference
0  310000   first     100    2022-01-15 07:28:00       0
1  310000  second     100    2022-01-15 07:29:00      60
3  450000   first     200    2022-01-15 07:45:00       0   
4  450000  second     200    2022-01-15 07:46:00      60
5  450000   third     200    2022-01-15 07:47:00     120
```

Comment: Btw, the dates in the input and output are different

Comment: Good spot, I initiated an update of the question but i think it didn't apply :( - It has been fixed!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

##### updated answer: difference from start of group

```
df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'])

df['difference'] = (df.groupby(['id', 'serial'])['time']
                    .transform(lambda g: g-g.iloc[0])
                    .dt.total_seconds()
                    .fillna(0, downcast='infer')
                    )
```

output:

```
       id     key  serial                time  difference
0  310000   first     100 2022-01-15 07:28:00           0
1  310000  second     100 2022-01-15 07:29:00          60
3  450000   first     200 2022-01-15 07:45:00           0
4  450000  second     200 2022-01-15 07:46:00          60
5  450000   third     200 2022-01-15 07:47:00         120
```

##### older answer

Use a `groupby.diff`:

```
df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'])

df['difference'] = (df.groupby(['id', 'serial'])['time']
                    .diff().fillna('0', downcast='infer')
                    )
```

Output:

```
       id     key  serial                time      difference
0  310000   first     100 2022-01-15 07:28:00 0 days 00:00:00
1  310000  second     100 2022-01-15 07:29:00 0 days 00:01:00
3  450000   first     200 2022-01-15 07:45:00 0 days 00:00:00
4  450000  second     200 2022-01-15 07:46:00 0 days 00:01:00
5  450000   third     200 2022-01-15 07:47:00 0 days 00:01:00
```

Seconds as integers:

```
df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'])

df['difference'] = (df.groupby(['id', 'serial'])['time']
                    .diff()
                    .dt.total_seconds()
                    .fillna(0, downcast='infer')
                    )
```

Output:

```
       id     key  serial                time  difference
0  310000   first     100 2022-01-15 07:28:00           0
1  310000  second     100 2022-01-15 07:29:00          60
3  450000   first     200 2022-01-15 07:45:00           0
4  450000  second     200 2022-01-15 07:46:00          60
5  450000   third     200 2022-01-15 07:47:00          60
```

Comment: I get this error: `unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str'`

Comment: @Joe you should convert your strings to datetime type. See update

Comment: Works as expected. Just one thing. For the last one, it should be 120 because it should calculate it from the key=first of that group if that makes sense.

Comment: OK, then you don't want `diff`, see update